# Open application from a second Activity

Tags: java, android

I have an application that has a main Activity where you have several options to choose from, which entered different Activities. What I want to do is that once an option is selected, if I close and open again the application is started from second Activity (from the screen of the selected option).

This is my main activity but doesn't work:

public class InicioActivity extends Activity {

```
Button b1;
Button b2;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inicio);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
    ElegirIdioma();

    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("startFromSecondActivity", false))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EspanolActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}

private void ElegirIdioma() {

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("startFromSecondActivity", true);
            editor.commit();

            Intent aEspanol = new Intent(InicioActivity.this, EspanolActivity.class);
            startActivity(aEspanol);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Bienvenido" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    /*b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                    Intent aEnglish= new Intent(InicioActivity.this, EnglishMainActivity.class);
            startActivity(aEnglish);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Bienvenido" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });*/
```

}
}

Comment: use finish() keyword in onPause() method of the firstActivity..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can save that option in `SharedPreference` and in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method change for saved value and then you can `finish()` your `MainActivity` and start `SecondActivity`

put this in your `onCreate` method:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("startFromSecondActivity", false))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```

and put this in your `Button`'s `onClick` method :

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("startFromSecondActivity", true);
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner, you could give me an example of code?

Comment: Thank you very much, but in the onClick method asks me to create and initialize local variable sharedPreferences.I tried different ways but it does not work.

Comment: define `sharedPreferences` variable in your class. I guess you are defining it in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: Sorry, but that still doesn't work, I published my code. Thanks Anyway.

Comment: I just tested it and it's working. explain what you do for test your app.

Comment: Sorry, I kept trying and looked elsewhere how to do it and all give this solution. To test my app I click right button on the project> run as> android application on my phone, but when I do the phone is branded or application opens with a blank screen.You have any idea why?

Comment: Finally it worked correctly as you indicated. I was not extends of Activity, my mistake. Thank you Mohammad!